# How to upload image to database using Richfaces and JPA

Tags: jpa, file-upload, richfaces, seam

I am developing a web app on JBOSS AS 7 using Richaces 4, SEAM and JPA. I can not get rich:fileUpload working. I have no idea how to make it. When uploading image through rich:fileUpload, I need it to be inserted into the database. What I did right now:

1. I have an .xhtml page where there is a form for Uploading files (used one from Richfaces demo);
2. Created an entity bean UploadedImage.java (with @Lob annotation for image column);
3. DAO class to persist uploadedimage using entitymanager;
4. And UploadBean.java for view to connect it with EJB project;

Comment: What's the problem? Is there an error?

Comment: Right now I managed to insert bytes of image to database, but when I am trying to retrieve the image using a4j:mediaOutput, I get the following exception:
No handlers found for exception: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException : java.lang.RuntimeError : java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone will have the same issue, here is how to get it working:

Upload.xhtml (contains form for image upload):

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}"
                        stopButtonClass="file-upload-stop-button"
                        addButtonClass="file-upload-button" listHeight="0" listWidth="0"
                        id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp" allowFlush="true" maxFileQuantity="10">
                        <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none"
                            render="info, imgs" />
                    </rich:fileUpload>
```

FileUploadBean.java (delivering data to ejb class):

```
@Named()
@RequestScoped
public class FileUploadBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Inject
    private CMSDao cms;

    private Integer pid;
    private String name;
    private String aname;
    private byte[] data;


    public FileUploadBean() {}
    private ArrayList<UploadedImage> files = new ArrayList<UploadedImage>();
    private List<UploadedImage> filess;

    public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
            UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
            UploadedImage file = new UploadedImage();
            file.setName(item.getName());
            file.setData(item.getData());
            files.add(file);
            cms.insertImg(file);

        }
    //getters and setters
```

EJB class:

```
  public void insertImg(UploadedImage img)  {
            em.persist(img);
            em.flush();
        }
```

UploadedImage.java (entity bean):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="photo")
public class UploadedImage implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8192553629588066292L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="pid")
    private Integer pid;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="aid")
    private String aname;
    @Lob
    @Column(name="data")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private byte[] data;
// getters and setters
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code to you web.xml file

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize</param-name>
    <param-value>250000</param-value>
</context-param>    


<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The 250000 means 250kbs to the max request size file to be upload

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get it working but when I used the component I found it way to big and cumbersome. I'm using RichFaces but for this I use the Tomahawk component that is much simpler.

Keep in mind that you need multiPartForm support for file uploading...

MAG,
Milo van der Zee